# Differentiable implies continuous - in more dimensions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

I know that "differentiable of function f in $x_0$ implies continuous of function f in $x_0$".

Can I use the same proof to show that it is valid for a function $f: M \to \mathbb{R}^m$ with $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ ?
Since the definition of "differentiable" in "one-dimensional" is different from the definition of "differentiable" in "more-dimensional" i am not sure.

Comment: Yes. The condition for differentiability in higher dimensions is ever stronger in some sense. Start with it and try and write out a proof.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, this is true. By definition of the derivative of $f$ we know that the limit
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{|| f(x_0+h) - f(x_0) + D h || }{||h||} = 0,
$$
for some linear transformation $D$. Therefore since this limit exists, the following is true:
$$
0 = \left( \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} || h ||\right)\left( \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{|| f(x_0+h) - f(x_0) + D h || }{||h||} \right) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} ||f(x_0+h) - f(x_0) + Dh ||.
$$
By the triangle inequality,
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}||f(x_0+h) - f(x_0) || \leq \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}||f(x_0+h) - f(x_0) +Dh || + \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}||Dh || =\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}||Dh ||.
$$
But since $D$ is linear, it is continuous and $D0=0$, so the lattermost limit is just $0$. Thus $0$ is an upper bound for the limit, but since the norm is always non-negative, this implies that the limit is in fact $0$.