# If $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{|| f(x_0+h) - f(x_0) + D h || }{||h||} $ exists then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. True?

Tags: real-analysis

Been looking at this proof: [Differentiable implies continuous - in more dimensions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178534/differentiable-implies-continuous-in-more-dimensions/1178569).  And it appears we do not actually use the hypothesis of differentiability.  Rather it seems that:

If $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{|| f(x_0+h) - f(x_0) + D h || }{||h||} $ exists for some linear transformation $D$ then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Can anyone please confirm this is true?  And also what the significance in that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{|| f(x_0+h) - f(x_0) + D h || }{||h||} $ exists but is non-zero?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Thanks, I was "woozy"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ f(x_0+h) = \frac{ f(x_0+h)-f(x_0) - Dh}{\Vert h\Vert} \Vert h \Vert + f(x_0)+ Dh \to f(x_0)$$ if $h\to 0$.

Here it is essential that the limit exists, but nowhere it is necessary that the limit is zero. Also note that I used that a linear transformation is continuous such that $Dh\to 0$ if $h\to 0$.

Conclusion: Yes, what you claim is true.

Comment: Is the converse true?  That is if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ then the above mentioned limit exits?

Comment: I don't think that's true.

Comment: Yeah... I have trouble thinking of counterexample, I want one R^n to R...

Comment: Maybe you can ask in a separate question.